# Is there any point in using Asynctasks for api calls that require a response to proceed?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I feel that the answer to this question is too obvious, but part of me still wants to ask it anyway.

I am creating an Android app that makes several HTTP POST/GET requests using APIs when the app is launched for the first time by the user. All these requests are made by launching Asynctasks within the activity.

For example, there is an activity where athe user has to select an item from a list retrieved from the API. After he selects one, a progress bar is displayed to the user while the app sends the selection to the API to retrieve another list, and in the next activity, the user selects items from this list. Clearly, the user can't go this second list until a response has been received from the server after the app sends it the first list's selection.

In such a case, is there any point in using an Asynctask to send the selection of the first list, since the user is prevented from doing anything (by being shown a progress bar) until a response is received and the next activity is started. Wouldn't it make the code less complex if I just made the API call on the main thread?

I hope this wasn't too confusing.

Thanks

Comment: You want to cancel your AsyncTask and launch the second activity ? anyway, you can't request from main thread on Android

Comment: this will throw network on main thread exception.

Comment: there are already HTTPURLConnection Libraries that would just let you receive the return statement on your php code just check the okHttp library on android its fast and effecient

Comment: You are right api should have been hit on main thread in this scenario, but android sdk doesn't allow you to do it. Earlier it was possible though before api 11, but now it is mandatory to hit api on background thread using asynctask.

Answer (score 1):

I got your doubt completely. Good question. The root cause of the doubt because you are thinking you don't need to interact with the app till the process completes. But you actually want to. Event the progress bar will freeze if you could do something like it.

Ok, let's just assume you don't even have a ProgressBar. However, **handling the different UI components such as Spinners, EditTexts is not the only duty  of the main thread.** It should define different callbacks in the activity lifecycle. Doing big tasks in main thread will also freeze callbacks like onPause(), onStop() etc. That is why the 'NetworkOnMainThreadException' is being thew.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the detailed explanation. I forgot to factor in how it would affect the progressbar.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you cannot call the api on main thread as it will block the UI. Also now Android does not allow it to happen and throws 'NetworkOnMainThread Exception'. Its fine to use Asynctask for any task that takes few seconds and you get the callback in it , which in your case is required before you proceed to next screen.

Best way to do it is by using Networking libraries:

Refer this
https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have only used standard Android libraries so far. I will look into Volley.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you cannot do netwok call on main thread, it will raise [NetworkOnMainThreadException](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html) , You can still by pass this exception by adding the couple of following lines in your activity

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

but it is always recommended to perform network operation in background,
else it may cause your app to stop responding, and can result in the OS killing your app for being badly behaved , go through this article once [link](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2009/05/painless-threading.html)

Comment: That's interesting. But I think I'll play it safe and just prevent the exception altogether. Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0):

Any operation that takes more than a few seconds to perform should be added in a separate thread. All network operations should be performed on AsyncTask or do have a look at RxJava and RxAndroid. To be specific to your operation, any UI Operations during a network call can be performed in onPostExecute. If you're working with thread class then use a Handler.

Comment: Sticking to Asynctask for network operations does seem to be the general consensus. Thank you for the answer. I use a separate handler class that receives the parameters from the calling Asynctask inside an activity, sends it to the server, and receives and returns the response from the server.

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned, if main thread is used for network operation, it would make your app unresponsive.

User may want to start a different flow in your app by starting an activity from menu or action bar whatever is available in your app to start other flow.

Comment: That's the thing, actually. There are a few activities/fragments (mostly during the first-time use and setup of the app) that do not give the user an option to do anything else but wait while the app fetches a response from the server based on the user's input.

But I get now that it is simply not the right way to go about things by standard practice.